# Converting XML file with one node using simplexml_load_string()

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have simple xml file, with one or more nodes, for examle:

```
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
<nodes>
 <node>
  <value>Val1</value>
 </node> 
</nodes>
```

Is it possible, using `simplexml_load_string()` function, for file with one node (*as above*) to get:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [node] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [value] => Val1
                )
        )
)
```

with [0] key, like for a xml file with more nodes, not:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [node] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [value] => Val1
        )
)
```

Because next I need convert it to array with the same deep, whether from a file with one or more nodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SimpleXML already does what you want - the difference between the two is only in the output from `print_r`, which is showing the most *concise* way to access the elements, not the *only* way.

Specifically, `$xml->node->value` and `$xml->node[0]->value[0]` can always be used to reference the same node, and `foreach ( $xml->node as $node )` always works even if there is only one matching node.

This is why it is generally a bad idea to "blindly" convert an XML structure into a PHP array - instead, use `foreach` loops and property access to extract whatever information you need.

You can try it for yourself with this code:

```
// Single node
$xml1 = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
<nodes>
 <node>
  <value>Val1</value>
 </node> 
</nodes>
XML;

$sx1 = simplexml_load_string($xml1);
print_r($sx1); // misleading!
echo $sx1->node->value, PHP_EOL;
echo $sx1->node->value[0], PHP_EOL;
echo $sx1->node[0]->value[0], PHP_EOL;
echo $sx1->node[0]->value, PHP_EOL;
foreach ( $sx1->node as $node ) {
   echo $node->value, PHP_EOL;
}

// Two nodes with same name
$xml2 = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
<nodes>
 <node>
  <value>Val1</value>
 </node> 
 <node>
  <value>Val2</value>
 </node> 
</nodes>
XML;

$sx2 = simplexml_load_string($xml2);
print_r($sx2); // misleading!
echo $sx2->node->value, PHP_EOL;
echo $sx2->node[0]->value, PHP_EOL;
echo $sx2->node[0]->value[0], PHP_EOL;
echo $sx2->node->value[0], PHP_EOL;
foreach ( $sx2->node as $node ) {
   echo $node->value, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand it. Problem starts just when I try convert it to arrays...
I have other data in an arrays and i need compare/collate it with this data from xml file. 
Is it optimal to use arrays on the one hand and object on the other, or better convert it to the same type?

Comment: I thought about arrays because the functions array_intersect_key(), array_change_key_case() etc. were very useful to me.

Comment: Using arrays is fine, but don't expect to write a function that can convert any XML document into a useful array, because there's so many ways XML can be structured, and so many details you probably don't care about. Instead, look at the particular document you have, and loop through the bits of it you're interested in, building them up into your own array structure. For instance in this example, you might loop through the nodes and create something like `['Val1', 'Val2]` or `[ ['Value' => 'Val1'], ['Value' => 'Val2'] ]`.